# Undefined method each

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a show controller that pulls a record from a model (code below)

```
  def show
    @protocol = Protocol.find(params[:id])
  end
```

Now, I inspect @protocol and it is in fact returning an object:

[image]

My view is named show.html.erb and the code in show.html.erb is:

```
<table id="test-table">

      <thead>
        <% @protocol.each do |key, value| %>
          <th><%= value %></th>
        <% end %>
      </thead>

</table>
```

Essentially, in my view I want to loop through the @protocol hash and output each value. However I get an undefined method 'each' error as seen below:
[image]

Why am I getting this error? Can I not loop through a hash or is the return object not a hash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protocol is not a Hash, it's an instance of your `Protocol` model. You can't "each" a single record. If you want to iterate over the properties and their values, use `@protocol.attributes.each`.